# How do I use a Processing code in javafx?

Tags: javafx, processing

I want to know how I can integrate Processing in javafx to make my GUI.
Maybe a sample code could help to get me started

Comment: What do you mean by Processing? Please update your question with more information

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Processing is a framework/library for visualizations.

Comment: It is a programming language that I have used to draw the sketch of an aircraft . I would like to integrate it in javafx

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This answer is no longer valid as of Processing 3.

At its core, Processing is just a Java library that you can use like any other library in a Java application.

You create an instance of PApplet following the instructions [here](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/).

Once you have that instance of PApplet, you can treat it just like any other AWT Applet. Add it to JavaFX the same way you'd add any Applet to JavaFX. Some basic googling says that SwingNode is the component you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please help out with an example. I'm very new to this

Comment: I am getting the following error when i try to run my code:

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jssc.SerialNativeInterface.getSerialPortNames()[Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: @sj66 Did you google that error? It's caused by a missing native library. You'll have to google to figure out how to include a native library with your setup (IDE or command prompt).

Comment: Are you sure a PApplet may be added to JavaFX ? Seems I read somewhere it was not possible.

Comment: @incises Where did you read that? What happened when you tried it?